# python - extract several lines following a matched string

Tags: python, string, lines

I have two data files containing sets of 4 lines. I need to extract the sets of 4 lines contained in the second file *if* part of the 1st line of every set matches.

Here is an example of input data:

```
input1.txt
@abcde:134/1
JDOIJDEJAKJ
content1
content2

input2.txt
@abcde:134/2
JKDJFLJSIEF
content3
content4
@abcde:135/2
KFJKDJFKLDJ
content5
content6
```

Here is what the output should look like:

```
output.txt
@abcde:134/2
JKDJFLJSIEF
content3
content4
```

Here is my attempt at writing code...

```
import sys

filename1 = sys.argv[1] #input1.txt
filename2 = sys.argv[2] #input2.txt

F = open(filename1, 'r')
R = open(filename2, 'r')

def output(input1, input2):
    for line in input1:
        if "@" in line:
            for line2 in input2:
                if line[:-1] in line2:
                    for i in range(4):
                        print next(input2)

output = output(F, R)
write(output)
```

I get invalid syntax for next() which I can't figure out, and I would be happy if someone could correct my code or give me tips on how to make this work.

===EDIT===
OK, I think I have managed to implement the solutions proposed in the comments below (thank you). I am now running the code on a Terminal session connected by ssh to a remote Ubuntu server. Here is what the code looks like now. (This time I am running python2.7)

```
filename1 = sys.argv[1] #input file 1
filename2 = sys.argv[2] #input file 2 (some lines of which will be in the output)

F = open(filename1, 'r')
R = open(filename2, 'r')

def output(input1, input2):
    for line in input1:
        input2.seek(0)
        if "@" in line:
            for line2 in input2:
                if line[:-2] in line2:
                    for i in range(4):
                        out = next(input2)
                        print out
                        return

output (F, R)
```

Then I run this command:

```
python fetch_reverse.py test1.fq test.fq > test2.fq
```

I don't get any warnings, but the output file is empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using python3? In this case `print` is a function and requires the parenthesis: `print(next(reverse))`. Note that this works even in python2.

Comment: Note that your function `output()` doesn't `return` anything, and that you then try to shadow its name in calling it. You will also need to store your results in some container, pass it back to the caller and rename the variable before this will work at all.

Comment: Another thing to note: You are looping over `input1` once, but trying to loop over `input2` each time you hit a match; you'll read all of `input2` the first time `"@" in line` is true and then, as the filepointer is at the end of the file, will not read another line again. Your code needs to gather all matching `@` lines from `input1` *first*, then loop over `input2` searching for matches, instead.

Comment: Next thing wrong: `line` will include a newline character, `line[:-1]` is the same line without the newline, that last digit is still going to be present.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks, I'm not sure where to place `return` but will try; I corrected the name shadowing.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh, this is very useful, I'll try putting in `input2.seek(0)` after `for line in input1:` thank you. OK, maybe it will work with `line[:-2]` :)

Comment: In the future, don't just say "I get invalid syntax". Post the traceback. Even if _you_ don't understand what it's saying, people on SO will. If it's pointing at the `print` you're probably trying to run Python 2 code on Python 3; if it's pointing at the `next` you're probably trying to run Python 2.6 code on 2.5; or it could be a missing `)` on the previous line; or…

Comment: @abarnert OK, will do, sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split out the reading of the first file from reading the second file; gather all lines you want to match (unless you are reading hundreds of thousands of lines to match). Store all lines you want to match, minus the digit at the end, in a set for fast access.

*Then* scan the other file for matching lines:

```
def output(input1, input2):
    with input1:  # automatically close when done
        # set comprehension of all lines starting with @, minus last character
        to_match = {line.strip()[:-1] for line in input1 if line[0] == '@'}

    with input2:
        for line in input2:
            if line[0] == '@' and line.strip()[:-1] in to_match:
                print line.strip()
                for i in range(3):
                    print next(input2, '').strip()
```

You need to print the matched line too, then read the next *three* lines (line number 1 was already read).

Comment: Thanks let me try! (actually, I am reading hundreds of thousands of lines...)

Comment: @biohazard: Then you *really* don't want to keep re-reading the `input2` file over and over again. If the set doesn't fit in memory, use a database (like `sqlite`) instead.

Comment: Thanks! I tried your script but it says "AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'strip'" for the last line.

Comment: @biohazard: right, closing parenthesis in the wrong place; corrected.

Comment: It worked with the test data set! Thank you so much!

Comment: _if line[:1] == '@'_ - no need to slice, _line[0]_ will do

Comment: @volcano: unless `line` is empty. Which, come to think of it, shouldn't happen when iterating over a file (it'll be at the very least one character long).